# Regression with missing values

Tags: regression, spss

Please help.

I have 3 IVS and 1 DV in my model. The 3 IVs are rated by 150 Middle Managers while 50 Directors rate the DV. I need to conduct multiple regression. However for cases (rows in SPSS), where Middle Managers rate the 3 IVs, I have missing values for Directors' rating of the DV. How should I conduct regression? Do I need to restructure the data? Thanks.

Comment: What are you IV and DVs in this analysis? What's the question? I believe you might be interested in some form of inter-rater agreement based on the problem description.

Comment: Do you have a link between Middle Managers and Directors?  Is the DV such that it would, in real life, vary across Directors, or is it really just the rating of the DV that varies across Directors, and similarly for the IVs and Middle Managers?  In short, is there any reason to link the ratings of the 3 IVs given by a particular Middle Manager to the rating of the DV given by a particular Director?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you have missing data, you basically have a few options:

1. Drop those observations
2. Get better data
3. Make up data

The third option sounds awful, but it turns out that if your data is Missing Completely at Random (MCAR) or MAR (missingness is a function of observable characteristics), then you can do better by [multiple imputation](http://www.colorado.edu/ibs/crs/workshops/Missing_Data_11-15-2011/SlidesHandout.pdf).  That's the approach I'd strongly consider.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the DV was intentionally answered by Directors only (as Middle Managers were not eligible enough as per the literature to answer questions related to the DV) while the Middle Managers answered questions related to IVs. To elucidate, the Directors answered questions regarding innovation capability of organizations while the Middle Managers rated the behavior of their top management i.e. Directors. Hope it clarifies. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some example data?  From what your data looks like in my head, you may need to just run two totally separate regressions.

Comment: Please reach a screenshot of my SPSS data view through this link. Thanks.            https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D728823_61176011_46590

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to conduct a regression that relates the Director's ratings to those of the Middle Managers.  In that case, you will only be on really solid ground in conducting regression using the 50 cases that have data on both of these types of ratings.  @Ari B. Friedman's suggestion to use multiple imputation has something to recommend it, but from what I perceive or read between the lines about your context and your audience, this method may prove quite difficult and is also likely to be perceived as too speculative.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help. Please allow me to re-phrase this question. The 3 IVs in my study are answered by 150 Middle Managers while the lone DV is answered by 50 Directors. The aim of the research is to find the effects of the IVs on the DV. I was in the process of restructuring the data and the new attached screenshort seems to explain the question better. Thanks again for your help and appreciate your ideas. Screen shot: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D728823_61176011_46590

Comment: Hi again,I was going through an article with similar context and found that data aggregation may be what I need to do. I attach the relevant portion of the article herewith. If you could please take a look and give your comments, that will be great. Comments are very much appreciated. Thanks. Screenshot: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D728823_61176011_47943

Comment: It sounds like the organization, headed by the Director, rather than the middle manager, is the level of conceptual analysis.  If so, aggregation of the Middle Manager ratings of the IV would be justifiable.